# mouseDragged: on CGRect

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, quartz-core

I am trying to drag a `CGRect`, but nothing happens. The rect stays in the same place. Here is my `mouseDragged:` code:

```
-(void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent{

NSPoint eventLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
NSPoint location = [self convertPoint:eventLocation fromView:self];

int locationX = location.x;
int locationY = location.y;

[self setNeedsDisplay:TRUE];

if(CGRectContainsPoint(myRect, location)){

myRect.origin.x = locationX;
myRect.origin.y = locationY;
}
}
```

This code is inside of an `NSView`. I draw the rect `myRect` in `drawRect`:

Here is my drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{

int width = self.bounds.size.width;
int height = self.bounds.size.height;

myRect = CGRectMake((width/2)-50, (height /2)-50, 100, 100);


CGContextRef myContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(myContext, 1, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextFillRect(myContext, myRect);

 NSLog(@"drawRect: called");

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your `drawRect:` method?

Comment: I've added the drawRect: method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're always setting `myRect` to a constant value inside of `drawRect:`. It seems like what you want is to not set `myRect` at all in `drawRect:` and to draw it with its current value. So something like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef myContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(myContext, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillRect(myContext, myRect);

    NSLog(@"drawRect: called");
}
```